# "WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!" constantly occurring, even *after* deleting known_hosts

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh, scp

As per title, lately I started getting the error "WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!" after I set up a new server in AWS. I'm on OSX Yosemite (10.10.3)

I'm aware of nearly all the methods one can take to remove this error:

- `ssh-keygen -R <ip>`
- `rm ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Etcetera. I can confirm the file is deleted. I then open a new terminal and SSH in, adding the key once again to known hosts. However then if I attempt to `scp` into the server, I get this error again. I've even tried restarting my computer after clearing known_hosts and continuing the process then. It seems very strange whatever's going on. I've scoured the internet as best I can and I haven't managed to find anyone talking about this issue.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this might happen?

Comment: Do you get the error when you `ssh` in, instead of `scp` in?

Comment: No, this is the bizarre thing, it does what I'd expect and asks me to add it to the hosts file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What ssh options are you using? If you're not already, you should consider the following two

```
-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 
-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

You can put these in your ~/.ssh/config file or use them together on the CLI.

The other thing I was wondering is could it be that your instance is terminating and re-provisioning? That *would* change the host id. Just a thought.